# Proving limit by definition with absolute value

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

This is what I have:

$\lim_{x \to 0} x \cdot |x|=0$

And I know:
$$|x|=\begin{cases}x,&\text{if }|x|\ge 0\\-x,&\text{if }x <0\;.\end{cases}$$
Case 1:

$\lim_{x \to 0^+}=0$
$(0 < |x - 0| < \delta \Rightarrow |x-0|< \epsilon)$
since:
$o < x-0< \epsilon \Rightarrow \fbox{$\delta=\epsilon$}$

So:

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \delta =\epsilon, 0<|x-0|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - 0| < \epsilon $

Case 2:
$\lim_{x \to 0^-} x \cdot |x|=0$

And I know:
$\lim_{x \to 0^+}=0$
$(0 < |x - 0| < \delta \Rightarrow |-x-0|< \epsilon)$

And I'm assuming that (because adding or substracting zero is no relevant):

$(x+0 \Leftrightarrow -(x-0))$

And for absolute value property:
$0 < |x-0| < \epsilon$
So: $\fbox{$\delta = \epsilon$}$

With this I know the limit is the same, now I do the same with $\lim {x \to 0} x =$
$(0 < |x - 0| < \delta \Rightarrow |x-0|< \epsilon)$
With this I know :
So: $\fbox{$\delta = \epsilon$}$

This is by far the hardest in my book, doesnt contain the solution. Am I on the right track?

Comment: The function $f$ is defined with distinct formulae on $(-\infty, 1)$ and $[1, \infty)$, but from your working, I'm wondering if it should be $(-\infty, 0)$ and $[0, \infty)$. Could you confirm that the question is correct?

Comment: You need the formal $\epsilon-\delta$ part for $xf(x)$, like you did for $f(x)$ in the last line of Case 1.

Comment: Just a fix typo on the definition of absolute value: $|x|=\begin{cases}x,&\text{if }x\ge 0\\-x,&\text{if }x <0\;.\end{cases}$. In the first case must be only $x \geq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with, let's ignore any value of $x \ge 1$. We only need to consider function values close to $0$, so for our intents and purposes, $f(x) = |x|$. The only thing we need to be careful of is ensuring that $\delta \le 1$. That way, if $0 < |x - 0| < \delta$, then $|x| < 1 \implies x < 1$, and so $f(x) = |x|$ for all the $x$ we have to worry about.

So, we are showing $\lim_{x \to 0} x|x| = 0$. We have $|x|x| - 0| = |x|^2$, and this is less than $\varepsilon$ if and only if $|x| < \sqrt{\varepsilon}$. Thus, we can take $\delta = \min\{\sqrt{\varepsilon}, 1\}$, to ensure that $\delta \le 1$ as we needed above. We get,
\begin{align*}
0 < |x - 0| < \min\{\sqrt{\varepsilon}, 1\} &\implies |x| < \sqrt{\varepsilon} \text{ and }|x| < 1 \\
&\implies |x|^2 < \varepsilon \text{ and } x < 1 \\
&\implies |x|x| - 0| < \varepsilon \text{ and } f(x) = |x| \\
&\implies |xf(x) - 0| < \varepsilon,
\end{align*}
completing the proof.

Comment: It's worth pointing out too that we didn't actually *need* the condition $x < 1$; it was just something we could force that would make the question simpler conceptually. If we had simply let $\delta = \sqrt{\varepsilon}$, it actually would have worked, because $0 \le |x f(x) - 0| \le |x|x| - 0|$, even when $x \ge 1$ (verify this for yourself!). However, if $f$ had been defined differently for $x > 1$, then we may not have this, and our choice of $\delta$ as a minimum would have been necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you're quite far from a proof. Using $\delta=\varepsilon$ is not sufficient and you're never actually using the function that you want to find the limit of.

There is no need to go to one-sided limits. Your purpose is, given $\varepsilon>0$, to find $\delta>0$ such that, for $0<|x|<\delta$,
$$
\bigl| x|x|-0 \bigr|<\varepsilon
$$
Now the key observation is that $\bigl|x|x|\bigr|=|x|^2$.

Hence you're done by taking $\delta=\sqrt{\varepsilon}$. Indeed, if $0<|x|<\sqrt{\varepsilon}$, then $0<|x|^2<\varepsilon$.